# Linux-native C libraries: How to configure Visual Studio Code to work with them on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

total noob here.

There are a few a few C libraries I would like to use, like unistd.h and sys/time.h, in a Windows machine. I have found many threads discussing is it simply not possible without using alternative packages. But I wonder does the Windows Subsystem for Linux come with those libraries? If so, how do I configure Visual Studio Code work with WSL?

Comment: Need some modification before using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I wonder does the Windows Subsystem for Linux come with those
>   libraries?

Yes compiler in WSL will contain these headers.

> If so, how do I configure Visual Studio Code work with WSL?

You need to enable WSL in Windows features, install linux distro you like via Microsoft Store, install "Remote - WSL" extension in VS Code.
More information can be found here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl

Keep in mind though, that applications that you will compile in this setup will be linux applications. They will only be able to operate under linux or WSL.
There is no way you can compile applications using these libs for Windows. These libs are platform depended.